# How to change the group name in view dir (*.vws) since primary group in pvob is changed?

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm

I have a problem changing the group name in (*.vws) directory of the view since the cc primary group is changed on Pvob. It is not blocking me since I am the owner but my collegue is not been able to deliver in my view.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually use [`fix_prot`](https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_admin.doc/topics/r_tshoot_acls_fix_prot.htm) (see "[About `fix_prot`](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21142606)")

On Windows:

```
doskey fp=c:\Rational\ClearCase\etc\utils\fix_prot.exe -force -chgrp "TheNewGroup" -chown yourID $*
fp -rec -chmod 775 \\path\to\view\storage\yourID\yourView.vws
fp -root \\path\to\view\storage\yourID\yourView.vws
```

On Unix:

```
alias fp=/path/to/ClearCase/etc/utils/fix_prot -force -chgrp "TheNewGroup" -chown yourID
fp -rec -chmod 775 /path/to/view/storage/yourID\yourView.vws
fp -root /path/to/view/storage/yourID/yourView.vws
```

Note that if the group of the PVob has changed, you might have to change the group of the project, stream and associated branch as well.

```
cleartool protect -chgrp "YourNewGroup" stream:yourStream@\aPVob
```