# How can i modify vob group in clearcase in windows?

Tags: clearcase

My views are in **none** group but user and administrator is in **clearcase** group.so I am not able to access my vob in view server. How can i change my view group?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use [`fix_prot`](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_admin.doc/topics/r_tshoot_acls_fix_prot.htm?lang=en): see "[How to change the group name in view dir (`*.vws`) since primary group in pvob is changed?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25312491/6309)"

```
fix_prot [–f/orce] { –root [–r/ecurse] [–recover {–chown user | –chgrp group } |
  –replace/_server_process_group| [–r/ecurse] [–type { d | f }] 
                                  [–chown user] [–chgrp group] [–chmod permissions] } pname …
```

I usually define an alias first:

```
doskey fp=c:\Rational\ClearCase\etc\utils\fix_prot.exe -force -chgrp "TheNewGroup" -chown yourID $*
```

And then change the view properties:

```
fp -rec -chmod 775 \\path\to\view\storage\yourID\yourView.vws
fp -root \\path\to\view\storage\yourID\yourView.vws
```

Or, without the doskey (Windows alias):

```
c:\Rational\ClearCase\etc\utils\fix_prot.exe -force -chgrp "TheNewGroup" -chown yourID $* -rec -chmod 775 \\path\to\view\storage\yourID\yourView.vws
c:\Rational\ClearCase\etc\utils\fix_prot.exe -force -chgrp "TheNewGroup" -chown yourID $* -root \\path\to\view\storage\yourID\yourView.vws
```

Comment: Windows? I have only fix_prot.exe file. I tried this comment before it won't change, any other ways to modify group name?

Comment: @MohamedHanish see the link:you will see the Windows syntax there

Comment: @MohamedHanish I have edited the answer to include the Windows syntax

Comment: thanks for the tip. Got a follow up question. yourID is the login name or SID for the user?

Comment: @MohamedHanish generally, it is your login name, not the SID.

Comment: whenever I tried to execute below  commands,It shows invalid macro definition.
fp -rec -chmod 775 \\path\to\view\storage\yourID\yourView.vws
fp -root \\path\to\view\storage\yourID\yourView.vws

Comment: Because .vws is not created in my local directory. I have used dynamic view to access the folders. Can you please tell if it is dynamic view what can I do?

Comment: @MohamedHanish did you defined `fp`? (the `doskey fp` command)

Comment: @MohamedHanish snapshot or dynamic views would be processed identically by `fix_prot`.

Comment: @MohamedHanish  .vws is never created in your local directory: it references a view workspace, managed by the view server, in a shared path: do a `cleartool lsview -l -full -pro <yourViewTag>` to see that path.

Comment: Thanks Vonc. I got the path. After executing the first command In my view properties the group name has changed. I am not able to execute the second and third commands it throws an error like invalid macro definition. So still it throws an error "Access denied". Is there any other way to change properties of view?

Comment: By first command, do you mean the doskey one? It is an alias needed for the second and third commands

Comment: yes. I executed doskey command. but not able to execute the second and third commands. while I tried it throws the macro is not recognized or invalid macro definition. But I used /macro:all command to confirmed the fp macro is available in doskey macro. Is there anyother way to change the permissions of .vws?

Comment: after execting "fp -rec -chmod 775 \\path\to\view\storage\yourID\yourView.vws
 " command it shows "Reproduction complete".
Then I executed below
 "fp -root \\path\to\view\storage\yourID\yourView.vws "
It shows
View:<view path> <owner> <group> <additional group(**None<Don't know why it is shown none>**)> 
drwxrwx--x <owner> <group>

Comment: Now I tried to access view folder again shows "access denied".

Comment: @MohamedHanish rights for views can only be modified with `fix_prot`. You don't need the alias (it is here only to avoid repeating common parameters), so you can try and expand the `fix_prot` command, combining the alias with the second and third parameters.

Comment: I expanded fix_prot and executed successfully. As I mentioned above  I got the output which  I have mentioned below
output:
 "Reproduction complete".  and "drwxrwx--x <owner> <group>"
But still not able to access the folder. Is there any other parameter or permission I have to check?

Comment: @MohamedHanish that looks better! What a `cleartool lsview -l -full -pro <viewTag>` returns? Do you see the new group applied there in the view properties?

Comment: Yes. It shows everything (Including view_getinfo ).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76408/discussion-between-mohamed-hanish-and-vonc).