# VOB Server Operation make container permanently failed

Tags: centos7, clearcase

```
Environment:
VOB Server OS – CentOS – 7.6
Clearcase Version   - 8.0.1.19
Client: Windows-10
Clearcase Version - 8.0.1.19.
Interop - Environment
```

**Problem:-**
Created new VOB on CentOS VOB server then created VOB tag on Windows side using region synchronizer.  The VOB group created on CentOS side with the same name group created in Windows side as well. However from windows when I tried to add a new file using `clearcase explorer` (Or) through `clearfsimport` command it shows below error.

[image]

Followed the workaround provided/suggested as per below link, but not working.

```
https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/vob-server-operation-create-container-failed

[root@VOB-Server ~]# cleartool desc vob:/vobstorage/vobs/test
versioned object base "/vobstorage/vobs/test"
  created 2019-12-16T10:03:45+05:30 by ccuser.ccvobgrp@VOB-Server
  "Test VOB"
  protected by rolemap: "DefaultRolemap"
  effective access for user "root": rmelem,Read
  VOB family feature level: 8
  VOB storage host:pathname "VOB-Server:/vobstorage/vobs/test.vbs"
  VOB storage global pathname "/net/VOB-Server/vobstorage/vobs/test.vbs"
  database schema version: 80
  modification by remote privileged user: allowed
  atomic checkin: disabled
  srfm: disabled
  evil twin detection: disabled
  VOB ownership:
    owner ccuser
    group ccvobgrp
  minimum client feature level: 8
  ACLs feature level: 8
  Attributes:
    FeatureLevel = 8
```

From VOB server side no error from `/var/adm/rational/clearcase/log/vob_log`

Answer (score 1):

Your [IBM support page](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/vob-server-operation-create-container-failed) is about "`vobsvr_create_container`" (and related to a permission issue), not about "`vobsvr_make_container_permanent`" (seen [here in  different context](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PI15615))

On the (Windows) client side, double-check:

- your `CLEARCASE_PRIMARY_GROUP` (should be `ccvobgrp`), and make sure the user is part of that group
- your view (used by the `clearfsimport`) rights, in particular its group. You might [need to `fix_prot` it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25312491/6309)

On the server side, check if there is any disk space issue which would prevent this operation to complete itself.

---

The [OP Kishore](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4948798/kishore) reports [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59372665/vob-server-operation-make-container-permanently-failed/59373448?noredirect=1#comment104997869_59373448):

> I have created new VOB with `FeatureLevel = 7` using (`-flevel`) option, it is working fine on my windows snapshot view.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204545/discussion-on-answer-by-vonc-vob-server-operation-make-container-permanently-fai).